# What is the unit of the Rydberg Constant?

Tags: atomic-structure

In the image, the Rydberg constant seems to have two units. How is that possible?
[image]

Comment: Inverse centimeters are/were a commonly used unit for spectroscopy. http://how-it-looks.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-convert-to-and-from-wavenumbers.html

Comment: But why did they equate it with joules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert between joules (units of energy) and inverse centimetres (conventional units of [wavenumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber)) simply requires multiplication by a factor of $hc$. This is because

$$E = h\nu = \frac{hc}{\lambda} = hc\bar\nu$$

Of course, they are not *literally* equal, but they are physically equivalent.